# Getting null when invoking sibling component function

Tags: reactjs

I am implementing a scrolling functionality on the same page when the `Contact Us` button is clicked. The `Contact Us` is contained in a child component (`MyNavbar`); when clicked, it will scroll to a  fragment contained in another child component (`MyContactForm`), which is sibling of `MyNavbar`.

Here's the parent component:

```
// App.js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import MyNavbar from './components/MyNavbar';
import MyContactForm from './components/MyContactForm';

export default class App extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        ...
    }

    scrollToContactForm = () => {
        this.refs.contactForm.scrollTo();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <main>
                <MyNavbar onClickToContactUs={ () => this.scrollToContactForm() } />
                <MyContactForm  ref="contactForm" />
            </main>
        );
    }
}
```

And here are the two child components, `MyNavbar`

```
// MyNavbar.js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Navbar, Nav, NavItem, NavLink } from 'reactstrap';

const MyNavbar = (props) => {

    return ( 
        <Navbar>
            <Nav>
                ...
                <NavItem>
                    <NavLink href="/products/"> Products </NavLink>
                </NavItem>
                <NavItem>
                    <NavLink href="/services/"> Services </NavLink>
                </NavItem>
                <NavItem>
                    <NavLink onClick={ () => props.onClickToContactUs() }  href="#"> Contact Us </NavLink> 
                </NavItem>
            </Nav>
        </Navbar>
    );

}

export default MyNavbar;
```

and `MyContactForm`:

```
// MyContactForm.js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Form, ... } from 'reactstrap';

export default class MyContactForm extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            email: '',
            ...
            inquiry: ''
        };

        this.setEmail = this.setEmail.bind(this);
        ...
        this.setInquiry = this.setInquiry.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        this.myRef = React.createRef();
    }
    setEmail(event) {
        this.setState( { email: event.target.email } );
    }
    ...
    setInquiry(event) {
        this.setState( { question: event.target.inquiry } );
    }
    handleSubmit(event) {
        alert("Thank you for contacting us. We will respond to you shortly");
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    scrollTo = () => window.scrollTo(0, this.myRef.current.offsetTop);

    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment ref={this.myRef} >
                <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    ...
                </Form>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}
```

The app runs, however when I click `Contact Us`, I get a message saying

```
this.myRef.current is null
```

How can I get this to work?

Comment: `ref` isn't a valid name for a prop. Also you're passing as a string and appending in a `Fragment` which isn't a DOM node.

Comment: did you try giving ref={this.myRef} for form element rather than react.Fragment ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what worked for me:

I replaced `<React.Fragment>` with a `<div>`. Putting the `ref` in `<Form>` doesn't work either, as it should be on a DOM node (HTML element, not React component). So `MyContactForm.js` becomes:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div ref={this.myRef} >
            <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    ...
            </Form>
        </div>
    );
}
```